# access the array->object -> array values

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to access the elements of  "values" array of object wns of array data in d3 , how can i ? i need to access these values to create bars.

```
 var data =  [{
             "labels": [ "scn1","scn2" ]},{
                "wns": [ {
                        "label": "scn1",
                       "values": [ -0.06,
                                   -0.15,
                                    -0.21]},
                         {
                        "label": "scn2",
                       "values": [ -0.04,
                                   -0.13,
                                   -0.41 ]} 

                        ]
            }];
```

say i need  to access values "-0.06" from data-> wns[0]-> values[0]  and "-0.04" from data -> wns[1] -> values[0].

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("p").data(data.wns[0].values[0]).enter().append(p).text ("place wns value")
```

or

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("p").data(data.wns[1].values[0]).enter().append(p).text ("cts wns value")
```

at JS console do not bind anything need help.context is that a new-bee trying to visualize data from a table...

Thanks

```
<<<<<<===============FOLLOWING IS WHAT IM TRYING TO ACHIEVE=============>>>>>>>
```

Have a table with two rows and three columns.first cell in the Row are the labels needed for  bar chart, columns are the "WNS" values where each column represents a stage.

```
                WNS
scn1     -0.06 -0.15 -0.21
scn2     -0.04 -0.13 -0.41
```

I need to create a grouped bar chart where all the numbers in a row form a group.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).

Comment: You are missing, that data is an array --> `data[1].wns[0]...` and your `append(p)` should be `append("p")`. Maybe you could give more information on what you want to do? there is probably a more convenient way to access/bind the values than your approach

Comment: looks like i cannot post an image unless i have reputation :)..let me see how i can articulate what i want to achieve.

Comment: updated description to elaborate on what i want to acheive.